# Power a single light from two switch legs

Tags: circuit-design, ac, switches, relay

I have two switch legs, each with multiple lights.  I would like to connect a single light to both legs.  I think I figured out how to do this using a SPDT relay, but I do not have much experience with relays.  Is this a safe solution?  Is there a better one?
[image: SPDT]

Comment: It's not clear how everything is connected. Can you finish the schematic? Also, it sounds like you just want a light that is on all of the time, is that right? What are the other switches for? Is it two SPST or one DPST? Exactly what kind of "lights" are we talking about?

Comment: Ok, I added the neutral connections.  Not on all the time, only on if one or both of the two SPST switches are on.  The purpose of the switches is to turn the lights on and off. 
 The light I want to be on both switch legs is fluorescent.  The other lights are a mix of fluorescent and LED.

Comment: Will these be on different physical circuits i.e. fed from 2 different circuit breakers?  It matters a lot, especially in split-phase or 3-phase country.

Comment: Both circuits are fed from the same single pole circuit breaker.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkxyti.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Left: Your proposal. Right: A simpler solution.*

Your circuit should work. I've redrawn it in a "more-easy-to-follow" arrangement with the live at the top and neutral at the bottom. You can now consider current just flowing from top to bottom. (Yes, I know it alternates.)

An alternative is to replace the switches with DPST type. There is less to fail with this circuit but beware of shock hazard at each switch due to possible back-feed from the other. Both switches would also have to be on the same phase and circuit-breaker. Your relay solution avoids both those problems.

Comment: Thank you.  I believe you are proposing two DPST switches.  To my knowledge, SPDT switches alternate between the two outputs.  I do not believe I have ever seen a DPST light switch.  That would also require me to run a third conductor from the switch box beside the existing two, whereas the relay can be installed anywhere along the existing runs.  While near each other in the diagram, physically the switch box is next to the door and the lights are on the ceiling throughout the room.

Comment: "*I believe you are proposing two DPST switches.*" Correct. Fixed.

Comment: It appears Leviton makes DPST light switches, like the CS215 and CSB2 series.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem.

An axiom of every electrical code is that in any given cable or conduit, currents must balanced, equal and opposite, and "cancel each other out".  That means that if "live/hot" currents on a cable add up to 9 amps, neutral current must be 9 amps.  Current cannot go to a device on one cable's live, and come back on another cable's neutral.

Each wiring diagram, when showing cable routing, must be a "tree" and not a "loop".

Thus, many arrangements are easy to draw on a schematic, but very hard to implement on a wiring diagram.

DPST switches are readily available, at least in the North American marketplace.  So here is one way to do that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhNt0H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Here live is brown, neutral is blue. Alternate live colors: Red for lamps group 1, orange for lamps group 2, pink for special lamp.  "/3 cable" (aka 3-core) for the run between switches*.

Or, a separate hot-neutral pair could be extended from each of the two lamp strings, and wired with a relay like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEUcjH.png)</sup>

Note how the two neutrals are treated as different things - expressly for the purpose of assuring neutral current returns on the same cable as live current.

Comment: Thank you for expanding your comment into an answer.  It took me a long time to understand what you are saying, but I think I figured it out.  If you, for example, picture the current installation as two separate switch legs running down different sides of the room, with the light I want on both switch legs in the center of the room, then I could not implement my original solution by connecting to both of them because I would always be using the neutral on one side of the room, even while I was using the hot from the other side.  In my case both switch legs and the neutral are always together.